# Is there any difference between "&&" and "and"?

Tags: c++, operators

Is there any difference between doing `&&` and `and`? e.g:

```
bool resA = (a and b and c);  
bool resB = (a && b and c);
```

Are `resA` and `resB` identical or if not how exactly do they vary and why would one choose one over the other?

Comment: I can't believe it's not a duplicate.